# How to make a polygon from contour lines extracted from a raster QGIS 3.6?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, contour, extract, polygonize

I'm trying polygonize the elevation level 200 m of Europe map from raster GeoTIFF (The raster is projected in EPSG:3120).
At first I tried with Raster > Extraction > Contour, but the lines are interrupted in many parts so using lines to polygon didn't convert it well, joining the line at interrupted path. 
Then I tried with Vector geometry > Polygonize which in some cases created the polygons but in the major part of the map couldn't create polygons.
After that I thought to try it directly from raster using at the process toolbox from GDAL > Raster conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector), this took about 24 hours and didn't finish the process so I canceled.

I'm stuck at this point. The other elevation levels (500m, 1000m, etc) looks fine. Maybe they have less data than 200m. 
Can someone tell me whats wrong or a solution for this ?

Comment: you might be better of using vector data, example https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/dataset/contours/europe/#9/66.4981/6.1303 has contours for europe (14.85GB download).

Comment: well i think that i have a different area of Europe map bigger then openmaptiles bounds and need to download Asia and Africa continent too, so the data its too large just for lvl 200m contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround can be creating a new raster with the raster calculator and the following formula:

`("Slopes@1" >= 200) * 200"`

Assuming that *Slopes* is the name of the source raster, the output will be a raster with pixel values 200 for source pixels values greater or equal than 200, and zeros for the rest.

Then you can poligonze that raster.

Comment: I'm sorry for late response, i'm trying this formula ("Slopes@1" >= 200) * 200" but the result its empty view https://prnt.sc/q8h2w3. I did raster calculator > ("Slopes@1" >= 200) * 200" > select layer. 
I tried another way before, simple formula  "Layer name" < 200 and the output was as i wanted https://prnt.sc/q8h519. As you can see there are too many small areas. Ill try to delete after polygonize using vector>geometry tools>add geometry attributes and deleting the assigned area.
But as i said it took 24 hours and didn't finish the process, so i canceled.

Comment: You say that take 24hs with the original raster. This is a raster with only two values. Can't take 24hs for that.

Comment: I don't remember in which layer used polygonize. Just to be sure I'm trying this now and still waiting. I'll let it till tomorrow. Hope to get some correct result.

Comment: After 3 hours and 30 min finally got the level 200 elevation polygonized. Thank you Gabriel

Comment: You are welcome Iven. I'm glad it worked. The detail of the raster was really too much.